# Feature engineering for interest-based age classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering, data-analysis

I have a dataset which has users (rows) with the list of their interests (IABs), which looks like this

```
user_id | gender | list of interests
--------+--------+--------------------------------
user 1  | male   | games, productivity
user 2  | female | games, lifestyle, design
user 3  | male   | travel, games, messaging
user 4  | male   | messaging, blogging, lifestyle
...
```

Since the number of unique interests are few (~500) and the number of rows are high (~67M), what are the feature engineering practices that I should follow to get an ML model score a better accuracy?

P.S.: Simple model with one hot/count hot vectorization yields an accuracy of ~52%

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon @theodre7, looking at what you showed, it's a little difficult to get a precise answer. But if it helps I'm happy.

Thinking about a simple model, with what I see in this table being a k-nearest neighbors user rating:

[k-nearest neighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)

Because it is very simple, it would be very useful for your "list of interests" column, but before building the model, it would be very good to use one-hot, these features transform columns, we will only have 0|1.

[OneHot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

In the gender column it would also be useful, but as it has two different data, with a replace method, "male"== 0 and "female" == 1.

It is also not enough to have a separate "list of interests", if you don't want to, but the interests would be more separated

After this processing, I would create the model, from the first link I passed. Reading the documentation, you can see the options that may be useful for you to work with. For this data sets. I left a link below that has an explanation about K-NN to help understand the concept.

[K-Nearest Neighbor](https://medium.com/swlh/k-nearest-neighbor-ca2593d7a3c4)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've tried similar methods (KNN, LR, SVM, etc.) with one hot encoded vectors but the accuracy hasn't budged a bit. I'm looking at some newer metrics which can capture the aspects of data which these models might not be able to after mere one-hot encoding

Comment: Good afternoon, do a cross-validation test. It could be that your set is learning from the data. [cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)